# Is it possible to prevent the connection attempt to EA online when starting the game?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-3

Whenever I start Mass Effect from the Xbox 360 dashboard it takes 15-30 seconds trying to connect to the EA servers. However, if I disconnect my ethernet cable it loads instantly.

I am not interested in any of the Mass Effect online components. Is there anyway I can disable this "service" while remaining connected to Xbox live?

Comment: Added the 360 tag to this, because I'm pretty sure you can't turn this off in the PC version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to auto-login to EA Origin is able to be turned off in Extra -> Options.

You cannot prevent the game from attempting to connect to EA Online if you have an active connection to Xbox Live and wish to receive game updates or DLC.

It is expected that the EA Servers will be heavily loaded during release week. Hopefully the times will go down as EA modifies the servers and excitement reaches normal levels.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the automatic connection to Origin in the options menu (for Xbox 360 at least).

Extras -> Options -> Online

Change "Auto Log-In to Origin (EA) to Off then back out and save your changes. The next time you start the game, you'll be given the option to connect to the EA servers by pressing Y, but it won't be mandatory